# Css overlapperd click

Tags: css, click-tracking

I'm building a strange div shaped structure and I need a hint to resolve a clicking problem.

This is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shyghar/A49Km/5/) to show you the issue.
The structure for each element is:

```
    <div class="views-row">
       <div class="diamonds-container">  
          CONTENT
       </div>
   </div>
```

I have a onclick() event on .diamonds-container but the .views-row div of the next element [with red or blue background..] go over the container and stop the click event on it.

I tryed to play with the z-index but I didn't have the expected result.

How can I achieve this structure with a correct click event on diamonds-containers ?

I think I can track the .views-row click with javascript and trigger manually a click on the previous diamonds-container but this will be my final option.

How can I achieve this without javascript?

UPDATE:

I have to position my diamonds like this
[image]
so I can't use the @matewka code because I will have the overlaping vertically instead of orizzontally..

Comment: your jsfiddle was empty and question incomplete. ?

Comment: I forgot to update the jsfiddle link ^^. Thankyou

Comment: Your question is still incomplete.

Comment: Incomplete and probably better suited for SO.

Comment: Now it's complete..  Does some admin want to move this question on SO? Or I have to insert this question there too?

Comment: Are these blue and red spaces in the jsfiddle neccesary? Or they're just for the problem visualization?

Comment: They are here just to show you where views-rows go over the diamonds-containers. In my layout only the diamond shaped container are visible.

Comment: tbh I think I'd probably go for the javascript route,trying to detect clicks on strangely shaped overlapping elements sounds a bit hairy / possibly ending up with different behaviour in different browsers too?

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one route for this kind of problem.

If you use the rotation transform anyway, why not rotate the `.views-row` element to get the bounding box out of the way?

For recent browsers and IE11 there are pointer events. See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A49Km/4/).

```
.views-row {
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.diamonds-container {
    z-index: 9;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, to answer to your 'why not rotate the .views-row element?' question I had update the question. I will have the same problem il I rotate the views-row. 
This is a good fix but I must write a javascript for IE 10-9-8 anyway.. if I will find a more compatible solution is better but I think this is the only 'only css' solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach. I'm not sure if nesting two divs inside each other was for rotating purpose or had some other meaning. Anyway, I did it this way:

```
.views-row {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.views-row-first {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 195px center;
}
.views-row-even {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
}
.views-row-odd {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: -65px center;
}
```

Each `.views-row` is rotated and the transform origins are all pointed to the center of the middle div. Notice that the `transform-origin` values are multiplicities of the half of the width (130px / 2).
See the **[updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N3V6J/)** for the complete CSS. I also added a `:hover` property for `.diamonds-container` so you can see that they're all clickable.

## UPDATE

With the picture you added the problem became much more complicated. But I figured it out.
*Hint: If you can't wait for the fiddle - you'll find it at the bottom of the answer.*

### The idea:

Square boxes are nested twice. Each 2 `.diamond` boxes are wrapped with the `.pair-wrapper` div. That div is rotated *45deg* and it is repeated few times along its container. Each *even* `.pair-wrapper` has increased width to position its right-hand neighbour properly.

A bunch of `.pair-wrappers` are wrapped with the `.line-wrapper`. You can add as much `.line-wrappers` and `.pair-wrapper` as you want (remember - `.pair-wrappers` will break into the new line if they don't fit).

Finally, each `.line-wrapper` has fixed height and hidden overflow to restrict its children area from the top and the bottom. Each `.pair-wrapper` is positioned relatively and has negative `top` value.

The solution is based mostly on fixed values, both I could figure out a better idea.

### The code

Example HTML markup looks like this:

```
<div class="line-wrapper line-wrapper-odd">
    <div class="pair-wrapper pair-wrapper-odd">
        <div class="diamond-box"></div>
        <div class="diamond-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pair-wrapper pair-wrapper-even">
        <div class="diamond-box"></div>
        <div class="diamond-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pair-wrapper pair-wrapper-odd">
        <div class="diamond-box"></div>
        <div class="diamond-box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="line-wrapper line-wrapper-even">
    <div class="pair-wrapper pair-wrapper-odd">
        <div class="diamond-box"></div>
        <div class="diamond-box"></div>
    </div>
    .....
</div>
.....
```

And the most important parts from CSS (complete CSS in the fiddle):

```css
.line-wrapper {
    height: 170px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.line-wrapper-even {
    margin-left: -92px;
}
.pair-wrapper {
    width: 130px;
    position: relative;
    top: -26px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.pair-wrapper-odd {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 65px 65px;
}
.pair-wrapper-even {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 92px 131px;
    width: 239px;
}
.diamond-box {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
}
```

### The fiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/N3V6J/3/**

Comment: Hi, thank you for this solution but I can't use it. I updated the question to explain you why

Comment: @Shyghar, please see my update. I hope this time it will help.

Comment: I will implement and test it on different browser. I will know you ^^